# Left join fails if not explicitly using ISNULL

Tags: sql, left-join, google-bigquery

I have a large table **User** and a small table **User_purchase** in google bigquery.

If I join the two with

```
SELECT User.id, User_purchase.amount FROM User 
    LEFT JOIN User_purchase on User.id = User_purchase.user_id,
```

the query returns error:

> Query Failed. Error: Not Implemented: This table cannot be read

But if I join the two with

```
SELECT User.id, ISNULL(INTEGER(User_purchase.amount), INTEGER(0)) FROM User 
    LEFT JOIN User_purchase on User.id = User_purchase.user_id,
```

the query works.

Don't quite understand why the first case does not work. 
I assume in the first case I can get all users with their purchase_amount though some users will have NULL as their purchase_amount.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some more information?  Like what kind of sql server(I'm guessing you're using MS Sql Server, but I'm not 100% sure).  Also I'm assuming the User.id and User_purchase.user_id are both ints, can you confirm?

Comment: It's google bigquery. Yes, integers.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, looking forward to your investigation result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug relating to nested field names in query replies. I've got a fix for the bug but it won't go out until next week's release. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response! Can you please update when the fix is released? thanks.

Comment: Should be available now. Let us know if you continue to have problems.